# IntelliJ IDEA annotation processing doesn't generate sources in configured forlder

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, annotation-processor

I'm struggling with IntelliJ Idea (*IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)*), *Gradle*, and *Immutables* library. What I'm trying to do is generating sources in the `generated` directory as expected by the configuration at [Using annotation processor in IDE > IntelliJ IDEA](https://immutables.github.io/apt.html#intellij-idea).

At the moment the result I get is that both compiled classes and sources are put inside `/build/classes/java/main` Have you got the same issues? Do you have suggestions to solve the problem? I'm looking for answers but I didn't find a working solution yet.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gradle, but with maven, it's taking this configurarion from maven compiler plugin instead of this Idea configuration, you refered. Maybe for gradle project you also need to find out proper gradle configuration.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA should use its configuration to process annotations. However, I'm looking/testing for a solution at "Gradle-side".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default Gradle puts all generated sources together with compiled ones.
Please configure it like this:

```
def generatedJavaSourcesPath = "$buildDir/generated-sources/java"
def generatedJavaSourcesDir = file(generatedJavaSourcesPath)

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs = [
            // Override the directory where to place generated source files.
            "-s",
            generatedJavaSourcesPath 
    ]
}
```

And to add generated sources to the project

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir generatedJavaSourcesDir
        }
    }
}
```

Just add it to the *build.gradle*